# Difference between Get-SPSite and Get-SPsiteAdministration

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, cmdlets

What is the difference between `Get-SPSite` and `Get-SPSiteAdministration` cmdlets?

I know `Get-SPSite` has more properties, but I want to know the core difference.

Appreciate if u could explain in detail.

Comment: Did you get your desired details in below answer? or you want something else as details for your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**FOR Get-SPSiteAdministrator**

The `Get-SPSiteAdminitration` cmdlet returns a site administration object that allows farm administrators to view certain information about site collections to **which they might not have access**.

**FOR Get-SPSite**

The `Get-SPSite` cmdlet returns either a single site that matches the **Identity** parameter, or all the sites that match the Filter parameter for the specified scope. The scopes are the **WebApplication**, **ContentDatabase** and **SiteSubscription** parameters. If none of these scopes is provided, the scope is the farm. If the scope is specified with no **Filter** parameter, all sites in that scope are returned.

The Identity parameter supports providing a partial URL that ends in a wildcard character (*). All site collections that match this partial URL for the specified scope are returned. Additionally, if the Regex parameter is provided, the Identity parameter is treated as a regular expression and any site collection with a URL provided in the given scope that matches the expression is returned.

The Filter parameter is a server-side filter for certain site collection properties that are stored in the content database; without the Filter parameter, filtering on these properties is a slow process. These site collection properties are Owner, SecondaryOwner, and LockState. The Filter parameter is a script block that uses the same syntax as a Where-Object statement, but is run on the server for faster results.

Valid values for LockState are: Unlock, NoAdditions, ReadOnly, NoAccess.

It is important to note that every site collection that the `Get-SPSite` cmdlet returns is automatically destroyed at the end of the pipeline. To store the results of `Get-SPSite` in a local variable, use the `Start-SPAssignment` and `Stop-SPAssignment` cmdlets to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: U mentioned 'site collections to which they might not have access.' for Get-SPSiteAdministration. So for Get-SPSite, site collections will not be returned to which he has no access. right?

Comment: If you need them than you need to pass some filter parameter with proper authentication.

Comment: **Get-SPSiteAdministrator** will get you them by default

Comment: one more thing, i want to compare the memory size of the PSObject returned by these cmdlets. which will be lesser?

Comment: Have you read this in above answer?....The Filter parameter is a script block that uses the same syntax as a Where-Object statement, but is run on the server for faster results.

Comment: Please check answers here...http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/whats-the-difference-between-spsite-usageinfo-storage-and-spsiteadministration

Comment: Is above information is fine for you?

Comment: no the above link is using in my case. I am not going to apply any filter. I going to get all site collections in the farm. something like this, *$sites=Get-SPSite -Limit All;   $sites1=Get-SPSiteAdminsitration -Limit All;*                                                                                                        which object will have less memory, $sites or $sites1?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40484/discussion-between-hardik-and-mani-dharmaraj).